# Document.location function for onclick links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hundreds of link variables.

```
var aa = "http://site1.com";
var bb = "http://site2.com";
var cc = "http://site3.com";
```

How can I implement an onclick function that when you click for example "aa" id font, it goes to aa link ?

```
<font id="aa">site1</font>
<font id="bb">site1</font>
<font id="cc">site1</font>
```

Comment: Don't. Use an `<a>` with an `href`. Why would you want to make `<font>` elements clickable, and thus make your page unusable for keyboard users who for whatever reason can't use a mouse or other pointing device?

Comment: For spesific reasons. But thats not the case.

Comment: Assuming you have a good reason for what you're trying to do, [what, actually, have you tried already?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `<font>` is a silly tag to be using in the first place. Use an `<a>` tag or people will hate your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this but you really should just use   a   tags if possible ...

```
<div id="myClickContainer">
  <font id="aa"> ... </font>
   .
   .
   .
</div>

<script> 
  var links = {aa: 'http://site1.com', ... }
  $("#myclickContainer").click(function(event) {
    location.href = links[event.target.id] 
  });
</script>
```